# How to navigate fragment url in angular 15

Tags: typescript, routes, angular15

I am trying to navigate fragment url in angular 15. But it is not working. So, How to navigate fragment url in angular?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fragment-url-scroll-to-w3ecdc

app.component.ts:

```
menuRedirect(){
    this.router.navigate(['/content', '#three']);
 }
```

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="menuRedirect()">Click To Three</button>
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let link of ids">
      <a [routerLink]="'.'" [fragment]="link">{{ link }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="section" *ngFor="let link of ids" [attr.id]="link">
    <h1>{{ link }}</h1>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Incidunt saepe
      exercitationem praesentium modi repudiandae dicta consectetur ab veritatis
      quaerat quibusdam quod, dolorem fugit temporibus voluptas magni ad odio,
      adipisci doloremque!
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```